# Formatting a thesis report - footnote area fixed height

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to fix the maximum height of the footnote are in my document. Right now the formatting is such that almost every page with footnotes looks completely different. I know understand that footnotes occupy area of the main text however, is there a way of fixing it to a certain height regardless of the number of footnotes on the page the document will look more uniform ?
@DavidCarlisle suggested \dimen\footins. I'll try that.

Examples of what I am referring to:
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

I hope this is a good example of what I am experiencing. Thanks for your assistance and patience with me.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{report} % leqno %(left equations)
\linespread{1.5}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspace
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry} %total={170mm, 220mm}, paperheight=400mm
\geometry{a4paper, left=30.5mm, right=22.5mm, top=30mm} 
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta ante vitae eros tincidunt bibendum. Aenean at odio consequat, feugiat tortor vel, bibendum orci. Sed tristique lorem lobortis lacus auctor, a facilisis sapien venenatis. Nunc malesuada eu leo id posuere\footnote{ante et rhoncus sagittis, sem arcu fermentum lacus}. Sed euismod lobortis ipsum nec pulvinar. Integer tristique, ante et rhoncus sagittis, sem arcu fermentum lacus, in tincidunt erat arcu vitae urna. Praesent in magna vel massa lobortis gravida ut et diam. Donec eget scelerisque lacus. Nam fermentum, libero in tincidunt tempor, urna velit vulputate lacus, id consequat tortor lorem at massa. Praesent auctor mattis lorem. Mauris vitae tellus pulvinar, pulvinar eros eget, hendrerit nunc. Quisque dictum quam a ipsum rutrum, sed venenatis metus maximus. Aenean quis lorem et ante posuere efficitur vel at enim. Vestibulum porttitor nisl nec egestas luctus\footnote{Praesent a dolor accumsan nibh lacinia varius. Morbi vel accumsan lectus, in mattis nisl. Quisque dictum quam a ipsum rutrum, sed venenatis metus maximus}.

Donec a imperdiet odio. Nullam sodales venenatis eros vel vestibulum. Nam ipsum magna, tristique nec diam non, ultrices tristique nibh \footnote{nisl nec egestas luctus enduarea}. In sollicitudin vestibulum massa at pretium. Phasellus justo sapien, convallis nec purus eget, egestas dictum est. Morbi ac ultrices purus, at lobortis quam. Vestibulum gravida diam quis iaculis aliquam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus sapien urna, eleifend eu ex ac, porttitor efficitur ante. Integer et sem in elit pretium fringilla. Fusce vel risus in risus pellentesque pellentesque \footnote{Donec lacinia vel nunc nec scelerisque}. Aliquam vitae commodo lorem. Donec lacinia vel nunc nec scelerisque. Nulla facilisis, libero ac sollicitudin mollis, purus mauris fringilla tortor, vitae mattis sapien metus non odio. Nam imperdiet malesuada nunc et pretium. Aliquam aliquet neque quis tincidunt lobortis.

Vestibulum aliquet feugiat feugiat. Nunc blandit rutrum diam eu dignissim. In sit amet dui vestibulum, tincidunt turpis id, dignissim ipsum. Aenean nec accumsan justo. Suspendisse bibendum risus a cursus commodo. Nam pulvinar odio et leo condimentum, eu gravida tellus lacinia. Suspendisse sed turpis a nisl aliquet commodo et ac magna. Suspendisse ac gravida urna. Donec hendrerit diam a laoreet laoreet. Pellentesque lectus mauris, consequat non interdum non, hendrerit ac enim. Proin eros massa, egestas non leo vitae, placerat consectetur elit. Donec sit amet malesuada turpis, eget gravida nibh.
\section{Second Chapter}
Sed pellentesque ex ut ipsum facilisis tempor. Suspendisse vestibulum arcu ut imperdiet pharetra. Fusce et gravida diam. Nunc quis rhoncus lectus\footnote{sapien ut nisl sodales tincidunt a sit amet est. Phasellus.}. Maecenas vulputate accumsan auctor. Nunc in sapien ut nisl sodales tincidunt a sit amet est. Phasellus quam dolor, maximus eget maximus a, ultricies quis odio. Proin hendrerit mauris quis ipsum tincidunt, id placerat sem porta. Pellentesque sit amet lectus vitae nisi placerat viverra.

Aliquam porta vehicula nibh, sed aliquam metus euismod at. Duis dapibus, nisi sit amet lobortis dapibus, ex sem consectetur justo, in vulputate orci velit id tellus \footnote{sapien ut nisl sodales tincidunt a sit amet est. Phasellus.}. Mauris a finibus tortor. Integer ut velit commodo, pulvinar elit sed, tempus leo. Phasellus sit amet risus condimentum, gravida libero a, luctus est. Praesent a dolor accumsan nibh lacinia varius. Morbi vel accumsan lectus, in mattis nisl. Aenean congue et orci nec porta. Nunc aliquam, sem eu vehicula pulvinar, elit sapien blandit velit, in interdum tellus tortor ut nunc. Mauris tempor ullamcorper odio. Sed aliquam, elit vel laoreet sagittis, ante est commodo nisl, id vestibulum dui nisl id eros. Nulla iaculis nisi a nibh varius, nec blandit dolor consectetur. Donec fermentum luctus metus vitae scelerisque. Pellentesque bibendum cursus libero, et pellentesque ipsum pharetra ut. Mauris sed faucibus augue, in tempor sapien. Phasellus massa ex, vulputate pellentesque blandit vitae, eleifend ac quam.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your examples can be run to demonstrate the problem, I fixed the last one but again you have input files so no one can run the example `\input{Title}` also you have loaded pst-plot (which is clearly not needed in this example) which stops pdflatex being used.

Comment: you say the problem is on pages with footnotes but the example does not have any footnote so does not appear to be related to the question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed the example. I kept trying different settings without any success: \textheight, paperheight, bmargin, total{}. I want the height from the bottom of the text, baseline of the footer to the paper page to be the same height in pages with footnotes, right now it just changes dynamically on pages with footnotes and looks horrible.

Comment: Your question is about the footer appearing at different place on different pages but your example is just a single page so doesn't show anything? also it warns `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 14.49998pt` so you should put `\setlength\headheight{15pt}` in your preamble

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your feedback and patience with me.

Comment: I ran your 2page example and can not see anything wrong. I suspect that you are confusing the terminology "footer" is not where footnotes go it is a fixed block at the bottom of the page typically used for page numbers. you 1 and 2 are at the same position on the page.  footnotes take space _out_ of the main text area, so if you have more footnotes they take up more space up to a maximum amount of the page (`\dimen\footins` which is 8in by default.

Comment: Add option `showframe`  to the  \geometry` statement.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are correct, I am talking about the area where the footnotes. I understand that the footnote occupy area out of the main text area however is it possible to fix the footnote area to always have a fixed position regardless of the amount of footnotes.?

Comment: anything's possible but I can't guess how you want that to work, the footnotes can be (and in some disciplines often are) more than half the page, do you want to _always_ leave half a page just in case you have enough footnotes to fill the space??  Perhaps you want them always flushed to the bottom try adding `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` to see if that is more like the layout you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this seems better. I'm used to Word and that is the case there. Thanks !

Comment: Aside from realising your design for your thesis, keep in mind that it might be bad practice. If you have fixed heights for footnotes, parts with many footnote references will not be printed on the same/next but on pages afar from the initial anchor point in the text. If you want a constant layout without different footnote-'boxes' on every page-footer maybe you want to use endnotes?

Answer (score 2):

By default footnotes start at the end of the text block so if the page is not full the space required to pad the page comes below the notes. This seems natural enough to me but if you want the padding space to come between the text block and the footnotes then you can use

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

Comment: and everyone here thanks a lot for you guidance!